# Resumable XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a data import tool which parses huge XMLs (it uses a SAX parser, but adaptation is the least of my problems). Failures, new deployments, system restarts happen, and I don't want to start entirely over, so I need to save the parser state (we can call it an XML cursor if we want) from time to time.

Are there any parsers out there capable of saving their states and resume them (obviously I have to seek into the file as well on resuming)?

I haven't found such a parser, so I have doubts about that, so here's my second question: do you have any suggestions how I should start implementing it? Take a SAX parser implementation and dig in, or I would be better off starting from scratch?

If it matters, I need xml namespaces, but no schema/DTD check.

The cursors could also come in handy for pre-parsing the xml and distributing the work for parallel processing.

Comment: Failure happens? It should not happen in such a way that you need to parse all the xml again, now should it?

Comment: Maybe it's not a failure. Let's call it system restart. Deployment of new version of the app.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of failures? IO failures? XML parsing failures?

Comment: Is this failure as in crash and application exit?, So when you re run the file parser you want to resume on the next sibling of the last successfully parsed node?

Comment: It's not only failure (see above, plus I've edited the question). I don't mind reparsing a couple hundred entries, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the content really, can you write an XQuery to unambiguously find a node in the file.

e.g `<Item id="1000"/>`

if so after a succesful parse of a node persist it, then when you resume pass it in (null would equal start from first). Then move to the target node, move to the next, and on y va.

Comment: It's an option, but it still has to do a full scan up to the point where I was in the input file. I do have records with ids, but I have found that irrelevant, because you can't rely on them without scanning.

Comment: Only other option I can think of would be if you can access the filestream, and get position for a seek, bit iffy though that. Breaking the files up, or trying to make it more`robust would be the lateral thinking options